# Get the difference in days between dates in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with user related data in it. The `user_regdate`(datetime) field contains the date of the registration while the `user_verified`(int 1) contains if the user already confirmed his/her e-mail address. I want to create a timed event which runs every day at 03:00 and deletes all user records which haven't been verified (`user_verified` = 0) and the user registrated more than 3 days ago. So the question is: how can I calculate if the difference between the `user_regdate` and the `NOW` is more than 3 days?

This is my query:

```
CREATE EVENT clear_unconfirmed
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2015-04-09 03:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO  
    /*actual query which does the deletion comes here...*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function in MYSQL

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation

Something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),yourdatecolumn)AS DAYS
FROM yourtablename
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6289d/1)**